# Android Studio 3 build fails saying multiple AndroidManifests.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have a multi-module Android project with multiple product flavors and after upgrading to AS 3.0, I had to migrate following the migration guide. I have solved lot of issues around missing dependencies as well as duplicate definitions. But finally I got blocked here.

Here is my app module's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.droidtitan.lintcleaner'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

hugo {
    enabled true
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion project.targetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion project.buildToolsVersion
    testBuildType "canaryStaging"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('keys/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'AndroidDebugKey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('keys' +
                '/*****************')
            storePassword '*******'
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '**************'
        }

        materelease {
            storeFile file('keys' +
                '/*****************')
            storePassword '*********'
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '**************'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myeglu.android"
        minSdkVersion project.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.versionCode
        versionName project.versionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        testApplicationId "com.myeglu.android.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static', "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions", "-DANDROID_UNIFIED_HEADERS=ON"
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        canaryStaging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)

        canaryStaging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".canary.staging"
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        canary.initWith(buildTypes.release)

        elcloud {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            applicationIdSuffix ".elcloud.debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        elcloudRelease {
            initWith(buildTypes.elcloud)
            applicationIdSuffix ".elcloud"
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.materelease
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        canary {
            applicationIdSuffix ".canary"
            debuggable true
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion project.supportVersion
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }    

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../sharedlibs/ffmpeg/lib']
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// Cloud testing
    androidTestImplementation(name: 'cloudtestingscreenshotter_lib', ext: 'aar')
    //    implementation 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:1.7.0@aar'
//    canaryimplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-    android:1.4-beta2'
//    canaryStagingimplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-    android:1.4-beta2'
//    debugimplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-    android:1.4-beta2'
//    releaseimplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
//    testimplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
            implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:+') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$project.gmsVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$project.gmsVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$project.gmsVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$project.gmsVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$project.gmsVersion"
//    implementation 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:+'
implementation group: 'com.facebook.stetho', name: 'stetho-urlconnection', version: '1.4.2'
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:percent:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$project.gmsVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$project.gmsVersion"
implementation project(':foscamlib')
implementation project(':irlibrary')
implementation (project(':cctvlib'))
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:$project.gmsVersion"
implementation project(':shared')

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$project.firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:$project.firebaseVersion"


implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$project.supportVersion";
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$project.supportVersion";
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5';
//    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3';
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'
implementation 'com.turbomanage.storm:storm-api:1.0'
implementation 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
implementation ('com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3'
}
implementation 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.7'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.2@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'
implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.8@aar'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.6'
implementation 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.5.0'
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$project.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.kaknazaveshtakipishi:PermissionEverywhere:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.6'
implementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$project.espressoVersion"
implementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.supportVersion"
implementation ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$project.espressoVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'net.sf.kxml'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.turbomanage.storm:storm-impl:1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error message that I'm getting is as follows. But it doesn't give much clues as to which is the duplicate files' location.

```
Error:10:05:18.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] Cannot create tasks to upload Proguard Mapping File.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resolving configuration 'androidTestAnnotationProcessor' directly is not allowed
10:18:18.372 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForCanaryStaging'.
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'AndroidManifest.xml'
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
10:18:18.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
10:18:18.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 17m 14s
```

I have enabled debug build as well but still no clue other than the fact that multiple AndroidManifests.xml files are seen. Has anyone faced a similar problem? Is there something that I could be missing?

Comment: this may help you https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, you can see google group discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/JqnlnGK2ddY

Comment: These links are not really useful for my context. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: Have you find the solution? I'm encountering the same problem